# Spring WebSocket Stomp user connection and disconnection event broadcasts

Tags: spring-boot, stomp, java-websocket

I am using SpringBoot 3 with Stomp. I have defined two brokers:

```
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/chat", "/connect");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/chat");        
}
```

`chat` is used in the controller:

```
@MessageMapping("/broadcast")
@SendTo("/chat/talk")
public WsOutgoingMessage sendToAny(@Payload WsIncomingMessage wsIncomingMessage, Principal user, @Header("simpSessionId") String sessionId) {
    ...
    return wsOutgoingMessage;
}
```

The endpoint is also named `/chat` and I would like to broadcast to clients about connecting and disconnecting users:

```
@EventListener
private void handleSessionConnected(SessionConnectEvent event) {
    Principal principal = event.getUser();
    ...
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/connect", new UserConnectionEvent("connect", connectingUser.getId(), connectingUser.getName()));
}

@EventListener
private void handleSessionDisconnect(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
    Principal principal = event.getUser();
    ...
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/connect", new UserConnectionEvent("disconnect", connectingUser.getId(), connectingUser.getName()));
        
}
```

The client side has two subscriptions:

```
   StompSession.Subscription messageSubscriberSubscription = sessionStomp.get().subscribe("/chat/talk", messageSubscriber);
   StompSession.Subscription userConnectedSubscriberSubscription = sessionStomp.get().subscribe("/user/connect", userConnectedSubscriber);
```

The `messageSubscriber` is working but the `userConnectedSubscriber` is not. What is the subscription path for `userConnectedSubscriber`

Answer (score -1):

The second subscription is user specific, so you need this instead:

```java
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(USERNAME, "/connect", new UserConnectionEvent("disconnect", connectingUser.getId(), connectingUser.getName()));
```

`USERNAME` might be the `principal.getName()`.

#### References

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/websocket/stomp/user-destination.html